# Save html tag in model angularJS

Tags: angularjs, model, scope, tags, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to save the string

```
<div class="Page" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

In `$scope.Pages = [''];`
in angularJS
But when I use `ng-repeat` in HTML it displays as a string.
I want it to be a div rather a string.

Comment: have you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use ngBindHtml(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

It is also helpful to look at this link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

http://jsfiddle.net/Shital_D/75wbb0b2/2/

Do following 1. Download angular-sanitize.js
2. code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngSanitize"]);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.html = ['<div class="text-color">Your html code</div>',
                    '<div class="text-color">2nd div</div>',
                    '<div class="text-color">3rd div </div>'
                  ];
});
```